# Can Sharpshooter cause multiple 100% critical hit chance hits if timed perfectly?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-demon-hunter

Sharpshooter is a chargeable ability that allows for 100% critical hit chance if maxed, but only for the first hit.

Furthermore it is possible to shoot different types of projectiles with different speeds and set traps with a Demon Hunter.

Assuming I set a trap, shoot Nether Tentacles, wait and shoot Hungering Arrow, so that all of them hit perfectly at the same time. This means the monster walks into the trap and is hit by both projectiles at the same moment.

Will I actually land three 100% critical hit chance attacks or is there some kind of attack queue and one would be selected "randomly"?

Comment: While this was the case at launch, my understanding is that this has since been nerfed in a hotfix.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Any link for this? I thought SS lasted for 1 sec after initial hit.

Comment: I don't have a source either, but I can confirm what he's saying. It used to be possible to stack a line of Elemental Arrows and all of them would crit when they eventually hit the target, even if they hit more than 1 second apart.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I routinely use Hungering Arrow with Sharpshooter to get multiple critical hits on my initial attack, as recently as today post Tuesday patching.

According to [this link](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/passive/sharpshooter) the bonus resets 1 second after the initial hit, so in theory if you could time it right, you could take advantage of such an arrangement.

Answer (score 2):

The bonus resets a second after the attack. If you use multishot on a group of enemies each arrow that hits from the initial attack will crit, and if you can get another set of arrows (including travelling time) to the enemy as well, then these will also crit.

After the one second, Sharpshooter drops and begins regenerating again.